# load external image to empty symbol as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm trying to load an image to a symbol.

I've looked at every answer but seems they got side tract with similar solution but no explanation on how to get the image to appear in the empty symbol.

Here is my code I got here and works but image not assigned to symbol.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("Red_X.png"));

function onComplete (event:Event):void
{
    addChild(Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to wait for the Loader to finish and extract its content. Simply add the Loader right away.

To add to a different container, you have to call the add method on that container.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
empty.addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("Red_X.png"));
```